# Problemas con números capicua

Tags: java, algoritmos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class Capicua {

public static boolean esCapicua(int numero) {

    boolean rta;
    int residuo;
    int invertido = 0;
    int aux = numero;

    while (numero != 0) {
        residuo = numero % 10;
        invertido = invertido * 10 + residuo;
        numero = numero / 10;
    }
    rta = invertido == aux;
    return rta;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean probar;

    System.out.println("Capicuas de 4 cifras:");
    for (int i = 1000; i < 10000; i++) {
        int num = i;
        probar = esCapicua(num);

        if (true ==probar) {
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Con este código genero los números capicuas de 4 cifras, pero no he podido hacer que los números que sean capicuas se sumen y den otro número capicua pero de 5 cifras.
¿Podrian ayudarme?

Comment: Solo puedes sumar dos parejas para formar el numero capicua?

Comment: no entiendo pq no pudiste seguir. donde esta el resto del codigo? o con que te trabaste? no estas guardando los numeros en ningun lado...

Comment: brother, edita la pregunta colocando el texto que hay en la imagen :D

Comment: Es que lo que no se como hacer es sumar 2 números que sean capicúas. Y que su resultado sea otro numero capicúa

Comment: Debo mostrar cuales son esas sumas de numero capicúas de 4 dígitos y su resultado sea otro capicúa de 5 dígitos. Ejemplo seria 9999+2222=12221

Comment: Hola @Carlos191194. ¿Podrías **[edit]** tu pregunta para agregar el enunciado como texto en vez de imagen? Por favor, pensemos en quienes leen la pregunta desde un dispositivo con pantalla chica o tienen problemas de vista. Además, permitiría que otros con tu problema puedan encontrar tu pregunta en una búsqueda

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean esCapicua(int numero) {

    boolean rta;
    int residuo;
    int invertido = 0;
    int aux = numero;

    while (numero != 0) {
        residuo = numero % 10;
        invertido = invertido * 10 + residuo;
        numero = numero / 10;
    }
    rta = invertido == aux;

    return rta;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean probar;
    List<Integer> listCap5 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 1000; i < 10000; i++) {

        probar = esCapicua(i);

        if (probar == true) {

            for (int j = 1000; j < 10000; j++) {
                boolean probar2;
                probar2 = esCapicua(j);

                if (probar2 == true) {

                    boolean cap5;
                    int suma = i + j;

                    cap5 = esCapicua(suma);

                    if (cap5 == true && suma > 10000) {

                        if (listCap5.isEmpty()) {
                            listCap5.add(suma);
                        }
                        int bandera = 0;
                        for (int z = 0; z < listCap5.size(); z++) {
                            if (listCap5.get(z) == suma) {
                                bandera = 1;
                            }
                        }
                        if (bandera == 0) {
                            listCap5.add(suma);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Los números capicuas de 5 cifras a partir de la suma de los capicuas de 4 cifras");
    for (int p = 0; p < listCap5.size(); p++) {
        System.out.println(listCap5.get(p));
    }
}
```

Comment: aunque pareceria resolver el problema, esto va a devolver soluciones duplicadas, y ademas prueba siempre que un numero sea capicua o no, aunque ya lo sepa.

Comment: Devuelve soluciones duplicadas, resuelve parte del problema

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, esto resolvió mi problema. Dios te bendiga

Comment: Carlos191194, si te fue de utilidad dale like para seguir ayudando

Comment: Ya esta solucionado, ya no se repiten las cifras.